# Google My Maps importing gpx files

Tags: google-maps

I am able to successfully import gpx data to Google My Maps. Most of the gpx files I have imported are in English and I am able to move them into same layer. However, some gpx files are in another language and they can't be placed on the same layer as the English ones. Are there some tricks or tools to convert the gpx file to same format as the others?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by combining the two files?

Comment: I'm not trying to combine the files, just trying to put them on to same layer

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that you might be able to do is [download google earth pro](https://www.google.com/earth/desktop/) and load the files there, organize them all under one folder and then right-click the root folder > "save place as" > save as a KML file

Comment: Then import this resulting KML file to Google My Maps, right? Is the software free to use or are there some licensing costs?

Comment: Yes, Google My Maps supports importing KML files. The Google Earth Pro software used to cost money, but has moved to the public domain and can now be used for free.

Comment: After saving to kml and importing back to GM the metadata is lost

Comment: Couple things:
Is there some reason that you are using My Maps?
Do you have ArcMap or QGIS? The issues that you are running into seem to be a little bit more complicated that just combining files onto the same layer. It sounds like you are going to need to do some table edits. QGIS is probably your best bet since you asked about whether google earth was free. You are going to need to do some merges and some field calculator edits in the table to get everything looking nice. I am still a little unclear about what you want. are you wanting to combine everything so they have the same table?